# How to run an AWS Glue 1.0 Python Shell Job with the Current Version of boto3?

Tags: python, boto3, aws-glue

I need to use a newer boto3 package for an AWS Glue Python3 shell job (Glue Version: 1.0). I included the wheel file below from S3 as external Python Library:

```
boto3-1.13.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

However, `boto3.__version__` prints out `1.9.203` even if i see the following log:

```
Successfully installed boto3-1.13.21 botocore-1.16.26 docutils-0.15.2 jmespath-0.10.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 s3transfer-0.3.3 six-1.15.0 urllib3-1.25.10
```

For some reason, Glue Python Shell job is not letting me overwrite the boto3 package version with the wheel file. Is there any way to overwrite?

Comment: I've think this is something related with not having sufficient permissions. Some of the errors I've got are 'Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable' or 'ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'

Comment: @MiguelTrejo Thanks for your insights. Could you think of any solution?

Comment: I tried overwriting the default versions multiple ways but it still loads 1.9.203 version.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Thank you for trying. I tried using Python script to install the package and also tried reloading all boto3 modules using the package installed in user dist folder: `/glue/lib/installation/boto3`, which has the right version installed based on my wheel file, still couldn't overwrite the Boto3 package.

Comment: @YunLing, please pick an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this happening is that boto3 is already imported when the GLue job starts, therefore, the import statement is ignored by Python. You need to remove the imported package at the beginning of your Glue script. You need to insert following code to the top of the script:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/glue/lib/installation')
keys = [k for k in sys.modules.keys() if ('boto3' in k)]
for k in keys:
    del sys.modules[k]


import boto3
print(boto3.__version__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to run an AWS Glue 1.0 Python Shell Job with the Current Version of boto3.

1. Download the current versions of .whl files from pip.

- https://pypi.org/project/botocore/#files
- https://pypi.org/project/boto3/#files

  At the time I wrote this answer the current versions where

  - boto3-1.20.10-py3-none-any.whl.
  - botocore-1.23.10-py3-none-any.whl

2. Create a bucket and folder where you want to store python whl files that you might use for glue python jobs.

- s3://glue/python/lib/

3. Upload the boto3 and botocore whl files to the new folder in the s3 bucket created in step2.

- s3://glue/python/lib/botocore-1.23.10-py3-none-any.whl,
- s3://glue/python/lib/boto3-1.20.10-py3-none-any.whl

4. Create a Glue 1.0 python shell job and while doing so expand Security configuration, in the "Python library path" add the paths with a comma separating the the paths

   ```
   s3://glue/python/lib/botocore-1.23.10-py3-none-any.whl,s3://glue/python/lib/boto3-1.20.10-py3-none-any.whl
   ```
5. Create a new python script and at the top of the script have it remove the pre-imported boto3 package.

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, '/glue/lib/installation')
   keys = [k for k in sys.modules.keys() if 'boto' in k]
   for k in keys:
       if 'boto' in k:
           del sys.modules[k]
   ```
6. Import boto3

   ```
   import boto3
   ```

This is what my final template usually looks like

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/glue/lib/installation')
keys = [k for k in sys.modules.keys() if 'boto' in k]
for k in keys:
    if 'boto' in k:
        del sys.modules[k]

import logging
import boto3
import botocore


def main():
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s-%(name)s-%(levelname)s-%(process)d: %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger("GlueLogger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.info(f"Received sys.argv: {sys.argv}")
    logger.info(f"Using boto3 api version:{boto3.__version__}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```